# How to set file path as h1?

Tags: html, jinja2, mkdocs

## Problem

The titles of my Markdown notes are mostly in the filename, rarely at the `title` key in YAML, and never in the `#` heading. When built, most of the time Mkdocs renders the correct titles and headings, but for notes having the `#` heading right at the start of the note, it takes it as the heading as well.

Say we have the file `folder/filename.md` with the content:

```
# First heading
Lorem ipsum
# Second heading
Hello world
```

Then in the output file `folder/filename/index.html` we have:

```html
<h1>Firt heading </h1>
<h2>First heading</h2>
Lorem ipsum
<h2>Second heading</h2>
Hello world
```

Is there a way to tell Mkdocs to have `<h1>filename</h1>` instead, if there is no `title` key in YAML?

## Attemp

I notice in `override\partials\contents.html` there is this code:

```html
<!--
  Hack: check whether the content contains a h1 headline. If it doesn't, the
  page title (or respectively site name) is used as the main headline.
-->
{% if "\x3ch1" not in page.content and not config.extra['no-auto-h1'] %}
<h1>{{ page.title | d(config.site_name, true)}}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I try removing the if statement, keeping only

```html
<h1>{{ page.title | d(config.site_name, true)}}</h1>
```

But it doesn't work. I try searching but can't find any solution, just [this conversation](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1008) on how Mkdocs should handle this by default.

<sub>[Also asked on mkdocs/mkdocs repo](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/discussions/3217)</sub>